# Django ORM Query - How to Subtract Time From Model Field?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have query that returns `Max` time from my model field.

```
results = MyModel.objects.filter(
                id=pk,
                date__range=(start_time, end_time)
                ).values('my_id'
                ).annotate(max_time=Max('my_date_time'))
```

To this point, everything works great. Now I need to `subtract` time (60 min) from my `my_date_time` field.

The most convenient for me would be if I can somehow subtract the time directly in my html template. Any filters available for that?

If not, is there a way to use `MySQL SUBTIME()` function or Python `timedelta` with this query?

Suggestions and feedback is much appreciated!

If there already is a similar previously asked/answered question, somehow I missed it and I do apologize!

**Edit:**

Yes, the `my_date_time` field is a valid `datetime` model field.

Comment: Is the return value a `datetime` object?

Comment: Yes, the `my_date_time` is a valid `datetime` object

Comment: Then it seems you ought to be able to use a `timedelta` object to subtract 60 minutes from the `datetime` object returned from your query.


Edit:


Perhaps something like this
`datetime_object = mymodel_object - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)`

Comment: Nick, I tried and failed, can you provide a code sample? Much appreciated!

Comment: Nick, I'm not following your example. How can I use that with the above `results = MyModel.objects.filter(...` ?

Comment: Ahh, I glanced right over the `filter` method being used. The `filter` method returns another [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) object -- much like a list -- that you can iterate through. If you expect to return just one object, then you can use the [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) method instead. Otherwise, you'll have to first grab your object from the returned "list" and then from there you will be able to work on it as a single `datetime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta

results = MyModel.objects.filter(
                id=pk,
                date__range=(start_time, end_time)
                ).values('my_id'
                ).annotate(max_time=Max('my_date_time'))
for result in results:
    result['max_time'] -= timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I'm getting `'dict' object has no attribute 'date'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! Your help is much appreciated!